# How can I have a predictive Termination & Active model?

Tags: r, prediction

I am a newbie in R. I have a dataset. Year & Month Active is store in the network Enterprise. Termination is store that left the network Enterprise. With these two variables, I can calculate the turnover My turnover is `Termination / ((Active + Termination)) / (nb jours in the month)` Example : Janv. 2013 , Active = 593 , Termination = 100 , Turnover = 1,75%

My question is with my dataset in attachment how can I calculate the active number and the termination number until 12-2015 ?

Is it possible to have a view of the scenario?

Dataset:

```
Year Month Active Termination To (%) 
2013 1 5936 100 1,75% 
2013 2 6182 190 3,21% 
2013 3 6501 117 1,91% 
2013 4 6675 92 1,43% 
2013 5 6749 111 1,67% 
2013 6 6719 145 2,20% 
2013 7 6814 121 1,83% 
2013 8 6854 90 1,34% 
2013 9 6972 99 1,45% 
2013 10 7320 99 1,42% 
2013 11 7606 98 1,33% 
2013 12 7976 155 1,99% 
2014 1 7934 87 1,11% 
2014 2 8079 127 1,61% 
2014 3 8198 125 1,56% 
2014 4 8135 154 1,91% 
2014 5 8113 136 1,70% 
2014 6 8095 173 2,17% 
2014 7 8131 220 2,76% 
2014 8 7950 135 1,72% 
2014 9 7978 108 1,38% 
2014 10 8117 199 2,51% 
2014 11 8269 117 1,45% 
2014 12 8471 177 2,11% 
2015 1 8472 132 1,59% 
2015 2 8591 117 1,39% 
2015 3 8691 161 1,90% 
2015 4 8647 126 1,48% 
2015 5 8623 123 1,45% 
2015 6 8739 177 2,07% 
2015 7 8740 218 2,55% 
2015 8 8548 35 0,41%
```

Comment: You might take a look at the package 'forecast' ([here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf)), maybe `forecast.Arima()` in particular.

Comment: I've began my code :

install.packages("forecast")
library("forecast")

install.packages("fpp")
library("fpp")

active <- read.csv("Active.csv", sep = ";")
names(active)
attach(active)
active

str(active)
attributes(active)

# decompose time series
active.ts <- ts(active) 
active.ts
f <- decompose(active.ts)

I receive an error message : Error in decompose(active.ts) : la série temporelle a moins de 2 périodes